# File downloaded from gdrive is corrupted

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a problem downloading file from gdrive

I am using this code

```
 DriveService service = new DriveService();

            var Stream = service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://drive.google.com/open?id=blablabla");
            var result = Stream.Result;
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("MyFile.exe"))
            {
                result.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
```

But I am getting size of 103kB in MyFile.exe, and it has 800 kB.

I suspect that I am not getting download url right, as I right click on the file I want to download and get shareable link in this format: https://drive.google.com/open?id=blablaid

Comment: Have you looked at those 103 kb as text? I wouldn't be surprised if it was some json with a nice error message.

Comment: It is some html file starting like this <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;"><style>@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Roboto Light')....etc....TypeError("ES3 does not support getters and setters.");a!=Array...... etc....

Comment: Well that does look like some sort of error message. Formatted as html too. What happens if you open that file in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/ the Google Drive download link is https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[FILE_ID].

Otherwise you could also look at the Google Drive REST API (developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

Comment: Yes, this is it, just in my case it is not docs, but drive.google.